# Function generators vs class generators in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Why do function generators and class generators behave differently? I mean, with class generators I can use generator as many times as I want, but with function generators, I can only use it once? Why so?

```
def f_counter(low,high):
    counter=low
    while counter<=high:
        yield counter
        counter+=1

class CCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
    def __iter__(self):
       counter = self.low
       while self.high >= counter:
            yield counter
            counter += 1

f_gen=f_counter(5,10)
for i in f_gen:
    print(i,end=' ')

print('\n')

for j in f_gen:
    print(j,end=' ')  #no output

print('\n')

c_gen=CCounter(5,10)
for i in c_gen:
    print(i,end=' ') 

print('\n')

for j in c_gen:
    print(j,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling the `f_gen()` function produces an [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (specifically, a [*generator iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator)). Iterators can only ever be looped over once. Your class is **not** an iterator, it is instead an [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), an object that can produce any number of *iterators*.

Your class produces a *new* generator iterator each time you use `for`, because `for` applies the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on the object you pass in, which in turn calls [`object.__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), which in your implementation returns a *new* generator iterator each time it is called.

In other words, you can make the class behave the same way by calling `iter(instance)` or `instance.__iter__()` before looping:

```
c_gen = CCounter(5,10)
c_gen_iterator = iter(c_gen)
for i in c_gen_iterator:
    # ...
```

You can also make the `CCounter()` into an *iterator* by returning `self` from `__iter__`, and adding an [`object.__next__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) (`object.next()` in Python 2):

```
class CCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
    def __iter__(self):
       return self
    def __next__(self):
       result = self.low
       if result >= self.high:
           raise StopIteration()
       self.low += 1
       return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class is an iterable, but not an iterator itself. Each time you call `iter` on it, you get a new iterator.

If you want to replicate the behavior of the generator function with a class, then you want an iterator like this:

```
class CCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.counter = self.low
    def __iter__(self):
       return self
    def __next__(self):
       if self.counter > self.high:
           raise StopIteration()
       val = self.counter
       self.counter += 1
       return val
```